# Sidebar implementation in angular 4 issue?

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a side bar with submenu in angular4 + bootstrap 4.

so i have html

```
 <div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-2 collapse d-md-flex bg-faded pt-2 h-100" id="sidebar">
            <ul class="nav flex-column">
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Overview</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">Reports</a>
                    <div class="collapse" id="submenu1" aria-expanded="false">
                        <ul class="flex-column pl-2 nav">
                            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link py-0" href="">Orders</a></li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                <a class="nav-link collapsed py-0" 
                              >Customers</a>

                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Analytics</a></li>
                <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="#">Export</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
       </div>
```

and i am also provide the plunker in which i am trying.

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9fbMEcBj5cJBoywhqNwj?p=preview)

what is going wrong ? why it is not working?

Comment: Don't know what is your expected result but seem you need to refer to jquery and bootstrap javascript files also to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I think your main issue is the collapsed class on this "a" element:

```
<a class="nav-link collapsed" href="#submenu1" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#submenu1">Reports</a>
```

I removed that and also the missing css link in this plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/VOfeJEXZ4eNGT7wYPtHz?p=preview